# Can a function $f: \emptyset \rightarrow \omega$ exist?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

From Naive Set Theory by Halmos:

"Let us say that a function *f* whose domain is the set of strict predecessors of some natural number n (in other words, dom *f* = n) is an $\omega$-successor function if $f(0) = \omega$ (provided that $n \neq 0$, so that $0 < n$), and $f(m^+) = (f(m))^+$ whenever $m^+ < n$. An easy proof by mathematical induction shows that for each natural number $n$ there exists a unique $\omega$-successor function with domain $n$"(p. 74).

**1. What is the unique function with domain $0$?** (answered)

I understand (or potentially misunderstanding) that for $n>0$, $0$ is an *element* in the domain $n$, so $f(0) =\omega$. For $n=0$ though, $0$ itself is the domain and in fact it is empty by definition.

**2.** **Let $S(n,x)$ be "$n$ is a natural number and $x$ belongs to the range of the $\omega$-successor function with domain $n$".** **What is {$x: S(0,x)$}?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function is a collection of pairs, with first coordinate in the domain and second coordinate in the codomain, then the question becomes: What is the unique collection of pairs with no first coordinate? This is of course the empty collection.

If we denote the unique function $\varnothing\ \longrightarrow\ \omega$ by $f$, then $f(0)$ makes no sense, because $0\notin\varnothing$. This is why your excerpt states explicitly *"provided that $n\neq0$, so that $0<n$"*.

Comment: Oh I think understand now. So the answer would be the $f = \emptyset$?

Comment: Yes, as a set the unique function $\varnothing\ \longrightarrow\ \omega$ is the empty set.

Comment: If $S(n,x)$ is "$n$ is a natural number and $x$ belongs to the range of the $\omega$-successor function with domain $n$", is {$x: S(0,x)$} = $\omega$?

Comment: To the proposer: I assume that by the range of a function $f$ you mean $\{f(d):d\in dom(f)\}....$  Put $n=0$ in your 2nd Q.  Then $S(0,x)$ implies that some $(d,x)\in f$  for a  function $f$ with domain $0=\emptyset,$ which implies $f=\emptyset\land (d,x)\in f$, which is absurd. So $S(0,x)$ is false for all $x.$  So $\{x:S(0,x)\}$ is empty.